# Waking up Android for a call

Tags: android, voip, wakeup

I am making a VOIP call app. When a call comes in, it should open the app, even if the app is **closed or never opened**. We also need the call notifications to come in from a server.

I know apps like WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger do this, but how?

We are using a design similar to follows: [Build a Calling App](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged)

We have tried using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) as [recommended by Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock), and while there is moderate success, it does not work when the app is closed.

We are considering using a [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters) or [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) next, but it takes quite a bit of time to prototype, and I'd prefer to ask if anyone has any success or if there are existing plugins for this.

As I'm aware, there are also going to be restrictions on [Android 10](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). It says to use time-sensitive notifications, but these will still need to be triggered from a server somehow.

Comment: have you had any success with this?

Comment: @HamzaEzzaydia not really. We integrated Jitsi instead for this purpose.

Comment: I'm working a flutter app where I need audio calls only, Do you recommend Jitsi or Agora.io? please give me a tutorial of how to do it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your calling activity add this code. It will turn your screen on.

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
    } else {
        final Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

and in your activity manifest, define intent-filter as CALL

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CallActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When you receive notification from Firebase in onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage), open your activity

```
openActivity(CallActivity.class);

public void openActivity(Class<?> tClass) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, tClass);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```